# Google is not indexing my pages

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, noindex

I just typed a post title from a few days ago into Google with "quotes" around it and nothing is showing up.

Does Google hate me? I am doing nothing but white hat marketing and even took down the pictures that I ripped from other sites.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean [this post](http://winemaking-equipment.com/ywa56t98hcyc/), Google found it just fine [when I searched for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=YWA56T98HCYC).  Considering you only posted it today, that's pretty good.

I would've recommended using [XML sitemaps](http://www.sitemaps.org) and the [HTTP ping feature](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_ping) to minimize indexing delays, but it looks like you're already using [a plugin that does that](http://betterwp.net/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps/).  To be honest, I can't think of anything else to suggest — it's simply a fact of life that there will always be a delay before Google notices changes to your site.  You can try to minimize it, but you can't eliminate it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Google indexes pages which have high traffic, metatags (keywords, descriotion), sitemaps etc, in order to get a better SEO for Google specifically, add these to your websites..

[Meta Tags Info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

Use 'Tags' for your posts, submit your sitemap. You can use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) to track your web page traffic.